# How to create azure acr task without providing git repository?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-cli, container-registry

I was able to create a azure acr task using the below command:

```
az acr task create --registry myregistry \
           --name demo_task \
                   --image demo_app:{{.Run.ID}} \
                   --file demo.Dockerfile \
                   --context https://github.com/hm-group/repo.git#branch \
                   --git-access-token your_token --debug
```

But, I don't want to provide git repository. Just want to use `--file` and tried build this task using below command:

```
az acr task create --registry productionai \
           --name demo_task \
                   --image demo_app:{{.Run.ID}} \
                   --file demo.Dockerfile
```

**Error:**

> If the task is not a System Task, --context-path must be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can provide `--context` as `/dev/null` if we want to use only file without providing context.

**Command:**

```
az acr task create --registry myregistry \
                   --name demo_task \
                   --image demo_app:{{.Run.ID}} \
                   --file demo.Dockerfile \
                   --context /dev/null
```